# Cosmos DB Partial Document Update with Filter Predicate

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having difficulty with a partial document updating my JSON data model stored in Cosmos DB.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is update the Individual Task nested JSON (example below) using the PatchOperation.Set (also tried PatchOperation.Replace) but keep getting the dreaded "Object Not Set To An Instance Of An Object" error.  Right before calling this method, I do a query to get the indexes so that I can dynamically set the index for Individual Task Sets and Individual Task since it may reside in a different place.  I'm using the filter predicate to get the right Individual Task since more then one can live under an Individual Task Set.

```
{
"GroupTask": [
{
    "_type": null,
    "GroupTaskID": "GUID",
    "GroupTaskTitle": null,
    "GroupTaskDescription": null,
    "IndividualTaskSets": [
        {
            "SETID": "GUID",
            "CreatedBy": "",
            "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "IndividualTask": [
                {
                    "IndividualTaskID": "GUID",
                    "TaskStatus": "",
                    "TaskTitle": "",
                    "TaskType": "",
                    "TaskDescription": "",
                    "TaskNotes": "",
                    "Priority": "Normal",
                    "CreatedBy": "",
                    "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
],
"CaseID": "GUID",
"TenantID": "testtenant0004",
"id": "GUID",
"TaskID": "GUID"
}
```

Below is the code that I'm using and the filter predicate string that I'm sending is the following "FROM Task t JOIN g in t.GroupTask JOIN its IN g.IndividualTaskSets JOIN it IN its.IndividualTask WHERE it.IndividualTaskID ='" + itid + "'"

```
    public async Task<string> UpdateIT(ReturnTaskObject rto, IndividualTask updatedIT, string path)
    {

        try
        {
            PatchItemRequestOptions patchItemRequestOptions = new PatchItemRequestOptions
            {
                FilterPredicate = path
            };
            ItemResponse<IndividualTask> response = await container.PatchItemAsync<IndividualTask>
                (
                id: rto.id, 
                partitionKey: new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.PartitionKey(rto.taskid),
                patchOperations: new[] { PatchOperation.Set("/IndividualTaskSets/" + rto.individualtasksetidorindex + "/IndividualTask/" + rto.individualtaskidorindex + "/", updatedIT)},
                //tried this approach without the filter predicate thinking that was the issue but also yields the same error  
                //patchOperations: new[] { PatchOperation.Replace("/GroupTask/0/IndividualTaskSets/" + rto.individualtasksetidorindex + "/IndividualTask/" + rto.individualtaskidorindex + "/", updatedIT) }
                requestOptions: patchItemRequestOptions
                );
            string status = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            return status;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Full Stack trace:

```
at CMaaS.Task.Service.DBUtil.UpdateIT(ReturnTaskObject rto, 
       IndividualTask updatedIT, String path)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at CMaaS.Task.Service.DBUtil.UpdateIT(ReturnTaskObject rto, 
  IndividualTask updatedIT, String path) at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at CMaaS.Task.Function.FunctionTaskController.RunUpdateIndividualTaskSetAsync(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at CMaaS.Task.Function.FunctionTaskController.RunUpdateIndividualTaskSetAsync(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
   at lambda_method149(Closure , FunctionTaskController , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.TaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.YieldAwaitable.YieldAwaiter.<>c.<OutputCorrelationEtwEvent>b__6_0(Action innerContinuation, Task continuationIdTask)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.YieldAwaitable.YieldAwaiter.RunAction(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
}
```

Comment: can you paste the whole stack trace?

Comment: @Sajeetharan thank you for looking into my issue.  Full Stack trace added above.

Comment: did u get this working? i just offered 500 points

Comment: i need to know how to execute Set on a node path that may or may not exist in cosmos

Comment: When you do a query of database links are created between the database and the c# classes.  An update uses the links from the query.  Somehow you broke the links or you never queried the database in the first place.  Creating a new instance of the object is one way you could break the links.

Comment: @Kuruption did you try out the answer?

Comment: @AlexGordon see if the below answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue.  The problem was I was still using the DocumentClient instead of the upgraded CosmosClient needed to work with patch update capability within Azure.  Once I changed that the functionality started working.

Answer (score 0):

For the set operation you just need to pass the value and the index of the object within the **`IndividualTaskSets`** array

```
patchOperations: new[] { PatchOperation.Set("/GroupTask/0/IndividualTaskSets/0/", YourObject)}
```

You can refer the sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097021/cosmos-db-patch-child-object)

Regarding your 2nd question, I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557547/cosmos-db-partial-document-update-with-filter-predicate).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the path wrong, it should be from the root.

Like this:

```cpp
List<PatchOperation> patchOperations =  new List<PatchOperation>(); 

patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Set("/GroupTask/0/IndividualTaskSets/"+ rto.individualtasksetidorindex + "/IndividualTask/" + rto.individualtaskidorindex, updatedIT))
```